# Is there API / SDK support for the credits section in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net

Is there API support for the credits section in AWS?

I am interested in redeeming credit programmatically via a promotion code.

I have looked through the .NET SDK documentation and developer’s guide and it seems that credits are not included in the SDK.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether via the SDK (.NET & others), CLI or API - there is currently no programmatic way to interact with AWS credits.